# What do these stamps mean?

Tags: seal

[image]The first stamp could mean Jing Zhao, no?

Sorry for the last one, I can´t have a better picture.

Thanks a lot,

Simon

Comment: The seals say (1) 臣景Ｘ and (2) 敬畫, can't see the character below 景. [Image enhanced here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvFGj.png). I think that bottom large square is also a seal, but it's impossible to read.

Comment: Thanks, I´m not sure but the caracter below 景 seams to be 昭

Answer (score 2):

my guess:

the first seal is "臣景昭"

the second one is "x畫",

the last one,

```
ｅｃａ
ｆｄｂ
```

the picture shown top 3 (ｅ, ｃ, ａ) & half the lower 3 characters (ｆ, ｄ, ｂ).

ｅ: the left component is 人 (radical 9)

ａ: the left component is 止 (radical 77)

anyway, here's the enhanced picture:

[image]

Comment: 止艮 is a variant of 跟. I also think the top middle is 不.